# Quickbook and GAS is not authorizing with Quickbook.js

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, oauth-2.0, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I'm new to this  (GAS)app script and apologize if not covered tech info.
I"m using the QuickBooks.gs, over excel sheet+ app script, when i select run, A pop was opened for authorization and QB access, after i gave access then i ended up with nothing.
debugging the logs helped me where i stuck.

```
function run() {
var service = getService();
Logger.log("checking the service status:", service.hasAccess());
if (service.hasAccess()) {
......
} else {
// If not authorized, get authorization URL.
var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
// View the Log to obtain the URL.
Logger.log('Open the following URL and re-run the script: %s', authorizationUrl);
```

```
[20-10-29 05:13:33:599 PDT] checking the service status: false
[20-10-29 05:13:33:620 PDT] Open the following URL and re-run the script: https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2?client_id=ABo6auye4WOq7sbmdShqz3NxTh9HfXex37kGkzeJMwZxr8xhFj&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fscript.google.com%2Fmacros%2Fd%2F14av1fKwiDvQL6WFUNTb7UtLcT0jy3HEMe2xza8fIEnN4CCD37YlFLcuo%2FusercallbawtUkrVfhPVUgtufeH_kSgr6DsCaSLe8uTIaH_fMIuBTQ7jrBl3411ugyRGZPXiNhT9beuHsmyyXFp3UVOrxv&scope=com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting&approval_prompt=auto
```

So I ended up with a "false" status. and asking me to open the URL, when i tried with link and QB reports the redirectUri is not set. I ran the function redirectUri and added the link to QB console under Keys & OAuth section, but still no go...

I tried with all mix sequences... :( nothing helped
If i forcefully run the script by `!service.hasAccess`, then i get Access not granted or expired.

So something im missing here.. but don't know what .......

Comment: In order to troubleshoot this, would you please consider providing the code related to `getService()`?

Comment: Here is the code for ref. 
https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/samples/QuickBooks.gs(guickbook.gs) _italic_

Comment: Are you sure that's the link you wanted to share? I'm getting a 404.

Comment: Ok, I had to remove `(guickbook.gs)` at the end. Did you retrieve the `CLIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET` from https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/get-started, as specified in the sample?

Comment: Ofcourse, I retrieved the placed key values.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I created an app at intuit in order to test this, and if I add the redirect URI to the developer portal and click `Save`, I can then go through the authorization process by accessing the `authorizationUrl`. Just to be sure, you clicked `Save` after adding the redirect URI, right?

Comment: I'm not sure about saving, I try your recommendation

Comment: It was working now,  seems i may not be saved it before i run after placing the redirect URI in the code.
Thank you for pointing out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the redirect URI to the to your app in the [Intuit Developer](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/homepage) portal, you need to click the `Save` button below; otherwise the list of redirect URIs won't get updated.